# Is it possible to activate an application or activity on an android handset from a c2dm server application?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, mobile, android-c2dm

I haven't done any android development as of yet but I'd like to write a client server application that allows a person to use a browser to interact with an application on their phone.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use c2dm to start applications or do other things like activities on an android handset?

Ideally I would run the server side in app engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start an application from your own when you receive a C2DM intent. But without being a system application, you will not be able to interact with other apps at all, beyond sending them intents.

Comment: I'm thinking that with the SL4A scripting environment one could kick off other things.

Comment: SL4A lets you do some development in scripting languages, but does not let you script UI interactions with apps that are not your own, unless they provided some intent that takes a script (very uncommon).

Comment: @Mike dg Could you be more specific about using C2DM? I wonder if i can activate GPS from C2DM.