# Activate GPS from server-side app to an Android app

Tags: android, gps

While i was thinking about GPS and server communication in an Android app, i though it would be really interesting give a turnaround, activating GPS from server-side app to an Android app. Is there a well-documented way to achieve this?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6035049/is-it-possible-to-activate-an-application-or-activity-on-an-android-handset-from) answer about using C2DM but they don't provide too much information about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one thing, in client-server communication, send some tag to client that GPS should be enable, and from Client(phone) if this tag is true, enable GPS, or start getting location update.

this is how i achieved the same in my app.

Comment: Ok, i believe i should use a broadcast receiver, do you have any example code to get this thing done? Thank you very much,

Comment: if you are doing client-server comunication, send request isGPSon to server, if server says true in response. start your gps tracking.. why do you want example for this.. it could be any request and response.

Answer (score 2):

C2DM is a bit of a black art -- best tested using curl -- but once your application successfully receives a message, you can respond to it in whatever way you like -- including starting GPS, etc

Comment: Could you send me some example code to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what part of this process do you need examples for?  C2DM?  turning on the GPS?